# Does not contain a definition for ToGridModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I can't seem to resolve the following error that states:

"System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for
'ToGridModel' and no extension method 'ToGridModel' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Linq.IQueryable'could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Any ideas about how I can resolve this issue?

Am I missing a "using" statement at the top of my file somewhere, or do I need to modify 
ToGridModel to some other kind of command?

I'm using Telerik **UI for ASP.NET Mvc**, **Kendo UI**,
and **Telerik Data Access**  extensions by the way.

I'm also receiving similar errors for the Viewbag as well in my Controller files.
I'm not too sure how to fix that major issue either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using Kendo.Mvc;
using KendoGridBinder;
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;

namespace AssetMgr_TeleMVC.Controllers
{
    public class SharedController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Shared
        // Exports the whole selected grid to csv in comma separated format 
       public ActionResult ExportCsv(int page, string orderBy, string filter)
       {
        //   IEnumerable orders = GetOrders().AsQueryable().ToGridModel(page, 10, orderBy, string.Empty, filter).Data;
        using (Model_OpenAccess_AssetMgr.ctx_OpenAccess_AssetMgr dbContext = new     Model_OpenAccess_AssetMgr.ctx_OpenAccess_AssetMgr())
        {  IEnumerable TableRows = dbContext.Assets.AsQueryable().ToGridModel(page, 10, orderBy, string.Empty, filter).Data;
           MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
           StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8);
           writer.Write("HSC TAG,");
           writer.Write("Asset Name,");
```

Comment: I recently upgraded the web application from Mvc3 to Mvc4 by the way. So that may be why this error is showing up if there is something I need to modify in the ToGridModel method in Mvc4 that perhaps worked okay previously in Mvc3

Comment: From [documentation on Telerik web-site](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/m_telerik_web_mvc_extensions_queryableextensions_togridmodel_1.html) seems that `ToGridModel(...)` resides in `Telerik.Web.Mvc.Extensions` namespasce in `Telerik.Web.Mvc` assembly. I don't see anywhere in your using statements reference to namespace. Try to add it, might help.

Comment: Well, I've recently migrated the web application to Kendo.Mvc (for Kendo UI) instead of Telerik.Web.Mvc. So that's why the Telerik.Web.Mvc.Extensions got removed because those extensions are discontinued currently by Telerik. They replaced it with Kendo UI.
So that's why I'm stuck with this issue b/c I'm not too sure what replaces ToGridModel in Kendo UI

Comment: I received this link from the support team at Telerik. Can any of you guys make any sense of this:
http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/export-grid-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent method in UI for ASP.NET MVC is `ToDataSourceResult`. You need to import the `Kendo.Mvc.Extensions` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Telerik.Web.Mvc.Extensions to your 'using' section. that's all